# PHP/MYSQL fetch results

Tags: php, mysql

I can populate results in PHP/MYSQL without problems and the sample code below can confirm that:

```
$query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, nums_ty FROM
       table_name
       WHERE nums_ty ='5' 
       ORDER BY id Desc";
```

I can view all records in the DB without hassle. What am trying to achieve is this: I want to create a form on the same page whereby a user can either select ALL to display all results or choose result based on date (WHERE date BETWEEN `'$startDate'` AND `'$endDate'`. But the default should be ALL.

Comment: What is your question? What have you written and how did it not work? What part do you need help understanding?

Comment: @dan Grossman Here is a scenario, I have an account listing page, User visit the page to view their transaction history and they get all transaction listed and paginated. That sorted! All am trying to do is, on the same page, I want to be able to filter the results using a form like: View history by Date or Month on the same page

Comment: That's a feature description, not a question. Add the form to the page and write the code to modify the query when it's filled out. If there's some part of that you don't know how to do, **that** might be a question. If you've written the code and some part doesn't work as expected, **that** might be a question.

Comment: Your SQL query string is actually a string. You have to build the query string depending on the user parameters. And watch out for SQL injection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
// check if user has selected a date range
// If yes, add the where condition    
$query  = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, nums_ty ";
$query .= "FROM table_name ";
$query .= "WHERE nums_ty ='5' ";

// Make sure both start and end dates are selected
if(!empty($startDate) && !empty($endDate)) {
    $query .= "AND date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' ";
}

$query .= "ORDER BY id DESC";

echo $query;
```

Comment: LOL yeah I hope the OP would sanitize the user input but good to point out. Love that Little Bobby Tables ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok by default you query all the rows and show it in your table,
i think you should use the $_POST or $_GET params with the function in php isset( ..param ) to evaluate if the dates in the form have been send, if that occurs you should use the mysql query with the dates criterias and after that just dispplay the results in your table or whatever

I hope this help u a little bit